# Semi showout from left for ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa

I want to have a button on the right of my app. when that is tapped, it must pull out a view from right on the to main view and it should only be 1/3rd size of the main view. Is there any control for this already written and open to use?

Comment: Few more details needed:1. Are you trying to animate a subview? 2. do you mean something like the facebook app?

Comment: Yes exactly like whats on the face book

Comment: See my answer, you well get a clear idea form it, should add some code as your own to reach your destination and please do accept if it helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do something like in the default Facebook app, you can follow this method.

First of all add the new `UIView` as a subview 
and in

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        CGRect customeFrame = CGRectMake(// set the frame parameters to keep the view out of visible region)
        [newView setFrame:customeFrame];
    }
```

Then in your button action, you can use `UIView` animation to bring the view to visible region
Like,

```
- (void)clickedButton
       {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                        //set the frame of newView to visible region
         CGRect customeFrame = CGRectMake(// set the frame parameters to keep the view in the visible region)
         [newView setFrame:customeFrame];
          } completion:^{
    //add what you need to do on completion
    }];
}
```

**NB :** I haven't set the frame for visible and hidden state of the `newView` as I need it to be set by yourself as per your requirements. Everything will be same except the `newView.frame.origin.y` property.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is what I actually thought of doing but I was looking for clean control. But reverted back to the old idea as what you mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use JTRevealSidebar: [download here](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo)

It has a button on the left side though.